# What data type is ideal for a float value ranging from -1 to 1 in TensorFlow/Numpy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, types

It seems for values with a fixed range, it is recommended in machine learning to min-max scale them between -1 and 1. What data type should be used for such values? It seems like a float[n] or double are the only options, but that also seems like it would be memory inefficient as a large portion of the available bits would never be used. Is this a meaningful concern in practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but that also seems like it would be memory inefficient as a large portion of the available bits would never be used

That's not how floating point works. It might be a concern for a fixed-point representation, but not floating point.

About half of all floating-point representable values have magnitude less than 1. Effectively, you're only sacrificing 1 bit worth of representable information per value by scaling values this way. (You can think of it as sacrificing the most significant bit of the exponent in the representation.)

Comment: Thanks! So the question remains, how do you choose the float's bit-depth? Would you go with the highest precision and decrease if it's not fast enough? Or go with the lowest acceptable precision?

Comment: @keysmusician you don't really need to care too much at this point in time, CPU and GPU have ALU and FPU with optimize circuits for all the most famose data types (maybe not `float64`), and the precision is almost ignorable in ML, since doing matrix multiplication, non linearity and so on have already many degrees of error (log, sin, cos, exp and so on are all approximations)